# Handling multiple forms on a single JSP

Tags: html, forms, jsp

I have a JSP page with several forms on it. Some of these forms are
generated dynamically, and each of them submits some information to a
database.

Handling one form is easy, as I can simply make the form post to
itself, and handle the
data using a single bean. Since I have multiple forms, I now have a
problem. Several of the forms on the page handle the same type of data
(same input names), and a 'setproperty *' call for each of the form
beans would change data in several beasn, not just the form/bean that
sent the data.

I am attempting to write a separate JSP with a single bean that
handles a form submission. However, I'm not sure how to make this page
go back to the referring page from which the data was submitted.

i'm going to reformulate in a simple way my question : 
I have one jsp, that lists an faq with one question and multiple answers. 
Each answer has its comment form, so its the same formbean.

I dont know how to set this...

Answer (score 1):

Use a servlet to control, preprocess and postprocess the request based on the request parameters. You can distinguish the form by the name and/or value of the submit button pressed. You can forward the request back to the JSP page by [`RequestDispatcher#forward()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29).